# python zelle graphics checkMouse()?

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

```
yes_box = Rectangle(Point(200, 150),Point(350,50))
yes_box.setOutline('blue')
yes_box.setWidth(1)
yes_box.draw(graphics_win)









def mouse_check(arg1): 
     ??????
```

Hey, have a quick question that is probably really obvious, but has me really stumped.  So I am writing a program(a game) that requires you to click inside the boungs of the yes_box(as shown above).  I am required to write a function that will check to see if the mouse click is inside the bounds of the rectangle, and return 'y' if it is, and 'n' if it isn't.

I know that you need to use the win.getMouse() and win.checkMouse() function, but I am not sure how to get python to determine if that click is in the bounds of the rectangle object?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't know the framework, but can't you get the mouse positon and compare it to the coordinates you use for the rectangle?

Comment: See, I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: So the actual question is "how to get the position of the mouse pointer in this graphics framework"?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get the point returned by `win.getMouse()` and make sure the x and y values are in bounds. I do that below in the `inside` function, then use this boolean value to display 'y' or 'n' on the window

```
from graphics import *      

def inside(test_Point, P1, P2):
    ''' 
    determines if the test_Point is inside
    the rectangle with P1 and P2 at opposite corners

    assumes P1 is upper left and P2 is lower right
    '''
    tX = test_Point.getX()
    tY = test_Point.getY()

    # first the x value must be in bounds
    t1 = (P1.getX() <= tX) and (tX <= P2.getX())

    if not t1:
        return False
    else:
        return (P2.getY() <= tY) and (tY <= P1.getY())


win = GraphWin("Box", 600, 600)

yes_box = Rectangle(Point(200, 150), Point(350, 50))
yes_box.setOutline('blue')
yes_box.setWidth(1)
yes_box.draw(win)

# where was the mouse clicked?
t = win.getMouse()

# is that inside the box?
if inside(t, yes_box.getP1(), yes_box.getP2()):
    text = 'y'
else:
    text = 'n'

# draw the 'y' or 'n' on the screen
testText = Text(Point(200,300), text)
testText.draw(win)

exitText = Text(Point(200,350), 'Click anywhere to quit')
exitText.draw(win)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this function:

```
p1 = rectangle.getP1()
rx1 = p1.getX()
ry1 = p1.getY()

p2 = rectangle.getP2()
rx2 = p2.getX()
ry2 = p2.getY()

x1 = point.getX()
y1 = point.getY()


if x1>=rx1 and y1<=ry1 and x1<=rx2 and y1>= ry2:

    return y
else: 
    return n
```

where point should be the point in which the user has clicked. and rectangle is the rectangle in which you want to know if the user clicked or not.